# Change Rails Console (IRB) Ruby Version OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, irb, rbenv

I am having some trouble getting rails to run with the correct version of ruby in the rails console. I would like to use ruby 1.9.3 in the rails console.

When I run RVM list I get:

```
rvm rubies

ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

When I run rbenv global I get:

```
 rbenv global                                                     
 1.9.3-p194
```

When I run rbenv local I get:
     rbenv: no local version configured for this directory

When I run ruby -v I get:

```
 ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
```

When I run RUBY_VERSION in 'rails console'

```
 irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.8.7"
```

When I run `which ruby` I get:

```
ruby: aliased to bundled_ruby
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think having both will cause issues. I'd recommend removing both and then adding either rbenv (my personal preference) or rvm back. Then go from there.

Comment: What does ruby -v show before you get into the console?

Comment: Still get the same outputs. Could it be the system ruby is getting precedence in PATH?

Comment: The system ruby is definitely still beating your version of ruby in your PATH. The system version is 1.8.7. How you could have `ruby` and not `irb` is weird though.

Comment: Can you run `env` and paste the result to get more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your rbenv is actually configured correctly. Test it by simply running `which ruby` and you should see `/Users/USERNAME/.rbenv/shims/ruby`. The real problem is when you run `rails console`. The `rails` command comes with osx, and you probably don't have a shim for it in rbenv.

Try `script/rails console` from inside the project dir.

Comment: just noticed it works when I run `script/rails console` but not when I run `rails console`. Why is that?

Comment: Yea just as I thought. So what's the output of `which rails`? I bet it's `/usr/bin/rails`. Try `gem install rails; rbenv rehash; which rails` and see if it changes.